# Изменение падежа при цитировании стихотворения

Tags: цитата

Ссылаюсь на стихотворение Лермонтова "Смерть поэта". Используется косвенный способ введения цитаты:

Эти черты были переняты им у "того певца... добычи ревности глухой" (М. Лермонтов. Смерть поэта).

В оригинале существительные употреблены в именительном падеже, в своём тексте я допускаю склонение в родительный. Кроме того, есть правило ставить косые чёрточки при цитировании стихотворения. Необходимы ли они здесь и стоит ли вторую часть цитаты писать с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 2):

1. Изменение падежа возможно, об этом говорится в [справочнике
   Мильчина, п. 8.1.10 "Изменение падежа слов в цитате против
   первоисточника"](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html#id-8%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-8110%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).
2. Что касается косой черты, то это вопрос скорее типографский, и он, насколько я знаю, однозначно не решён. Чаще используется одинарная косая черта с пробелами, но иногда двойная, а иногда черта вообще не используется, а в цитате просто пишется заглавная буква в том слове, с которого у поэта начинается новая строка: *Пушкин писал, что он "памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный, К нему не зарастёт народная тропа"*.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь в правильности оформления: некрасиво и неясно. У Мильчина берется словосочетание "пустословие довольно скучное" и в нем изменяется только  падеж.  А здесь не пойми чего...  разве можно использовать еще и неполное цитирование?

Comment: @Sharon разумеется, можно. "Можно опустить одно или несколько слов или даже предложений, если мысль автора цитаты не исказится и если читатель будет оповещен о купюре" (8.1.8). Также см. пункт 8.1.9 "Цитирование отдельных слов и словосочетаний". Но вы сомневайтесь, сомневайтесь)

Comment: Ну ладно, если можно, да только надо меру во всем знать.  В целом цитата выглядит неясной, как бы склеенной из кусочков.  Здесь же еще присутствует обособленное приложение, а это тоже ясности не придает. В общем, я считаю правильным то, что красиво. Вот и конструкторы говорят, что некрасивый самолет не полетит.

Comment: @Sharon во-первых, красота — понятие во многом субъективное. К тому же зачастую бывает так, что красивым начинает восприниматься привычное. Во-вторых, многое неправильное красиво, особенно если его эстетизировать. Этика versus эстетика — на этом построено многое в искусстве. Вряд ли вы увлекаетесь культурой видеоигр, но вот этот ролик я рекомендую вам посмотреть. Он не только про видеоигры, рассказанная там концепция — одна из основополагающих в искусстве. Да и в жизни, чего уж там. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idK3ycUS5_c

Comment: Спасибо, может, посмотрю, хотя играми не увлекаюсь.  А мнение у меня субъективное. конечно, но в каждой тематике субъективизм приобретает оттенки объективности. Вот у конструкторов самолетов, например.  Поэтому красота текста — это тема не для всех, а для тех людей, кто много работает с текстами.

Comment: @Sharon вы же сами привели пример с самолётом. Некоторые категории красоты заложены даже не в психике, а в фундаментальной физике. Можно вообще не шарить в аэродинамике, но увидеть, что самолёт красив. Можно не знать про золотое сечение, но видеть гармонию. Можно не знать про разрешение доминанты в тонику, но ощущать эстетическое удовлетворение от этого музыкального перехода. В текстах чуть сложнее, но чувствовать красоту текста — ни в коем случае не удел небольшого круга лиц. Профессионалы могут объяснить, *почему* то или иное красиво, но ощущать красоту способны не только они.

Comment: Наверное, вы правы.  Ну а вам лично нравится приведенное цитирование, вы находите его красивым? Или оно обычное, серенькое такое, но вас не раздражает?

Comment: Не нравится. Я бы написал: *Эти черты были переняты им у "того певца", который "добыча ревности глухой" (М. Лермонтов. Смерть поэта)*. Но вопрос всё-таки не про формулировку.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше так: Эти черты были переняты им у "того певца", который стал "добычей ревности глухой" (М. Лермонтов. Смерть поэта).  Как отвечать на такие вопросы? Я думаю, надо изложить теорию, применимую к этому примеру, но потом обязательно указать недостатки конкретного цитирования и привести корректный вариант.  А то у вас получается нечто такое: "Вам какие запятые лучше проверитЬ, в первой части предложения или во второй?" Ну прото как меню в ресторане.  В конце ответа всегда желательно указывать корректный вариант, а не только тот, о котором спрашивали.